# Get All local members and groups displayed together

Tags: powershell, csv, adsi

So far I have the below script that works like a charm but that only list the members of the group "Administrators". As my servers might be german, french ... I have no guarantee that such group will exist with the english word. So I want to adapt it to collect all groups and associated members instead of only Administrators... bummer I am stucked on a specific step

The script below list all users that are in non-empty local groups. However I would like to get in my CSV also the name of the group the user is part of, for clearer interpretations.

Can someone help me on this? I am a bit stucked and for quite nothing.

```
$Servers=Get-Content ListOfComputers.txt 
$output = 'ListOfLocalAdministratorsGroup.csv'
$results = @()

foreach($server in $Servers)
{
$admins = @()
$computer =[ADSI]"WinNT://$server"
$computer.psbase.children | where { $_.psbase.schemaClassName -eq 'group' } | foreach {
$group =[ADSI]$_.psbase.Path
$members = @($group.psbase.Invoke("Members"))
$members | foreach {
 $obj = new-object psobject -Property @{
 Server = $Server
 Admin = $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
 }
 $admins += $obj
 }}
$results += $admins
}
$results| Export-csv $Output -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local administrators group will always have the following sid: S-1-5-32-544 (documented at [Well-known security identifiers in Windows operating systems.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330/en-us))

So, you can add the following to your script to get the correct group name:

```
$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-32-544")
$objgroup = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$objgroupname = ($objgroup.Value).Split("\")[1]
```

Comment: Hello Trondh,

Sorry I edited in the meantime because I modified my script and almost got it working.

I will try your solution and let you know! :)

Comment: Trondh, I tried your answer but I'm getting "The group name could not be found" error with the Invoke method.

Comment: This way:

$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-32-544")
$objgroup = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$objgroupname = $objgroup.Value

foreach($server in $Servers)
{
$admins = @()
$group =[ADSI]"WinNT://$server/$objgroupname" 
$members = @($group.psbase.Invoke("Members"))

Comment: You need to get the $objgroupname in the for loop not outside of it.

Comment: @user1263785 I made an edit to the script (3rd line) - could you try again?

Comment: Thanks Websch01ar, however I keep getting the same error even with the 3 lines given by Trondh in the for loop :(

Comment: Trondh's edit will work, which I prefer.  You could also do this: ($objgroup.value) -replace "BUILTIN\\", ""

Comment: I do confirm that the edit of Trondh works like a charm !

I will post my entire code with the modification in 8h or more as I cannot answer my own question so quickly due to my status of newbie here :)

Comment: You should accept Trongh's answer to your question.  Then edit your OP below the original code with the final code.

Answer (score 1):

It works like a charm with the last edit of Trondh.

Here is the last version of the code. It will therefore gather all members of the local Administrators group (independently of the language used to name it)

Thanks a lot :) !!

```
#The Third section will query each computer in the ListOfComputers.txt to get the members of the local group Administrators
$Servers=Get-Content ListOfComputers.txt 
$output = 'ListOfLocalAdministratorsGroup.csv'
$results = @()

$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-32-544")
$objgroup = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$objgroupname = ($objgroup.Value).Split("\")[1]

foreach($server in $Servers)
{
$admins = @()
$group =[ADSI]"WinNT://$server/$objgroupname" 
$members = @($group.psbase.Invoke("Members"))
$members | foreach {
 $obj = new-object psobject -Property @{
 Server = $Server
 Admin = $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
 }
 $admins += $obj
 } 
$results += $admins
}
$results| Export-csv $Output -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hello to all, I have the same problem with languages over my domain, but copy/paste of this script gives me an error with Invoke: Exception calling "Invoke" with "2" argument(s): "The group name could not be found." the $objgroupname has Administrators and the admin group. I have a list of computers in the servers array.. I am missing something?