# Adding members to local groups by SID in multiple languages

Tags: powershell, sid

I'm new to powershell/scripting/life in general, but finally I got a problem that is worthy of asking for help:
I've various Windows localizations in environment - English, Finnish and Russian in current environment, but with possibilities to have other Scandinavian/European localizations. I need to add Authenticated users to Administrators group. I can script it in English:

```
NET LOCALGROUP Administrators "Authenticated Users" /add,
```

but I won't know all localized names. For example, in Russian it would be "Administratori" and "Proshedshie Proverku." In cyrilic, that I'm not that strong with anyway.
Of course, I know SIDs - S-1-5-32-544 for Administrators and S-1-5-11 for Authenticated users. However, running

```
NET LOCALGROUP S-1-5-32-544 S-1-5-11 /add returns error that group doesn't exist. Ok, so I found a script to check it -

$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("kenmyer")

$strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])

$strSID.Value
```

This returns expected value, so far so good. Then I tried to double check it -by running line to get name from SID -

```
$Admin = (Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Group -Filter "LocalAccount=True and SID='S-1-5-32-544'").Name

$Auth = (Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Group -Filter "LocalAccount=True and SID='S-1-5-11'").Name
```

And `$Admin` = Administratori (as it should be), while `$Auth` = nothing. There is no name. And that's where I stopped. I tried this in English environment as well - still got "no such group" message. Running first command I wrote, with both names in English - Works perfectly Ok.

Any ideas?

Upd:
Perhaps I can't explain properly what I'm trying to do, so let the script do the talking:

```
#Task: to add "Authenticated users" to "Administrators" group in any languange OS.
$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-32-544")
$objgroup = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$objgroupnameAdm = ($objgroup.Value).Split("\")[1]

$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-11")
$objgroup = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$objgroupnameAuth = ($objgroup.Value).Split("\")[1]

#Administratörer
#Autentiserade användare

net localgroup $objgroupnameAdm $objgroupnameAuth /add
```

I try this on Swedish Win7 right now. So result is:

```
net.exe : Syntaxen för kommandot är:
At line:13 char:4
+ net <<<<  localgroup $objgroupnameAdm $objgroupnameAuth /add
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Syntaxen för kommandot är::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

I've tried also putting `$objgroupnameAuth` in quotes, as it contains two words, but that gives same result. Definig variables as string - no changes, and replacing `$objGroupNameAdm` with actual value - no changes.

If I couldn't do it in English Windows, I would assume that it's just functionally impossible.

Comment: You may want to also try this question on the Security SE (http://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This answer should get you what you need:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288220/get-all-local-members-and-groups-displayed-together

Comment: @EricLongstreet, that link got me one step further - I can get both names in any language. However, when I try to add Authenticated Users to Administrators group, I still get error that "Can't be done, because user doesn't exist." Script still Works in English Windows - either with 'net localgroup' or '[ADSI]' from [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/11/25/use-powershell-to-add-local-users-to-local-groups.aspx) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is simple, once asked correctly, and answer is to be found here: [Microsoft Supprt: NET /ADD command](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324639/) .
If `NET` limit is 20 characters, and "Autentiserade användare" is 24 characters, it's not supposed to work. Workaround is to be found in the same link.

Answer (score 2):

I use this method to translate from SID to localized name:

.SYNOPSIS
Adds the "NT AUTHORITY\Interactive security principal to the local computer Administrators group"

.DESCRIPTION
THis script uses a SID translation to receive the localized name for the Interactive principal and the Administrators group, then adds the principal to the group using the localized names.

```
# Translate the S-1-5-32-544 (.\Administrators) SID to a group name, the name varies depending on the language version of Windows.
$sid2 = 'S-1-5-32-544'
$objSID2 = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($sid2)
$localadminsgroup = (( $objSID2.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]) ).Value).Split("\")[1]

# Translate the S-1-5-4 (NT AUTHORITY\Interactive) SID to an account name, the name varies depending on the language version of Windows.
$sid1 = 'S-1-5-4'
$objSID1 = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($sid1)
$interactive = (( $objSID1.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]) ).Value).Split("\")[1]

# Add the security principal name to the local administrators group. (used old style of adding group members due to compatibility reasons)

try {
    Write-Host "Adding security principal: $interactive to the $localadminsgroup group..."

    $group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:computername/$localadminsgroup,group"
    $ismember = "False"

    @($group.Invoke("Members")) | ForEach-Object {
        If ($interactive -match $_.GetType.Invoke().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)) {
            $ismember = "True"
        }
    }

    If ($ismember -eq "True") {
        write-host "user $interactive is already a member of $localadminsgroup"
    }
    Else {
        $result = $group.Add("WinNT://NT AUTHORITY/$interactive,user")
        write-host "user $interactive is added to $localadminsgroup"
    }
}
Catch {
    write-host $_.Exception.Message
}
```

It's not entirely tailored towards what you need but I'm sure you can make it work.

Regards,

Koen.

Answer (score 0):

The SID `S-1-5-11` is used for `Authenticated Users` ([Well known SIDs](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0)). That is a BUILTIN group that cannot be modified. Other groups like this are `Everyone`, or `Anonymous`, etc.

This type of group doesn't exist in the "physical" sense or the word, i.e. there is no object created either in the local SAM nor in the Active Directory.

They are entirely generated and managed by Windows.

You receive the SID in your session depending on how you connected and/or logged on.

Therefore making a [WMI Win32_Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394151%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) request, or using [Get-ADGroup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617196.aspx) won't return anything.

You can invoke [Get-ADAccountAuthorizationGroup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617214.aspx), to see if a particular identity is member of such groups.

You can use the SID to retrieve create a create a `System.Security.Principal.NTAccount` object pointing to `Authenticated Users`:

```
$auth = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-11") 
$name = $auth.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
```

UPDATE:
I could not add the localized name of $auth to that group. Looks like only the English version works.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to add local group "Authenticated users"  to local "Administrators" group. For practical purposes I could add "Domain Users" and that would give result needed - anyone is administrator on that machine - but that would be security breach, as it would allow unlimited remote Access etc.

Comment: You can use the Computer Management application (from the Console) to add it manually, alternatively I've updated the response to retrieve the object pointing to that group.

Comment: And if that will be only option, then we'll go with that, of course, however since it can be done in PS in English it should be possible to do it in other languages as well, I figured.

Comment: Yep, doesn't look like the NET command understands translated names.